# Connect to remote MS SQL Server using SSH tunnel

Tags: sql-server, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I need connect to remote MS SQL Server using SSH tunnel.
I have installed on remote server freeSSHd, set up router, allow TCP connection through 22 port.
I can connect to remote server using putty.
When I setup tunnels in putty - L1433 RemoteServerIP: 1433

So, I execute Microsoft SQL Management Studio, and try to connect to localhost(127.0.0.1). But instead of connection to remote computer Studio connect to local SQL. I logging putty session – but no information about tunnelling.

I made putty setting on the basis of the following article:
https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse444/11wi/resources/tunneling-instructions.html

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just use SSL? It's baked into the SQL product, so it's one less moving piece to troubleshoot. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898

Answer (score 2):

Is your local SQL server also listening on port 1433? (as you mentioned it connects to the local server)

If yes, then PuTTY will not be able to open port 1433 as the local side of your tunnel.

Use a different local port (-L) - one which is free on your system - when setting the tunnel up. And course, do specify this port when attempting to connect.

Comment: I turn off SQL Server service and SQL Server Browser. But result is same. Error message is different. In the first case Studio can not connect because wrong user name in the second case because server is unavailable.

Comment: Oh!  <br/>
I change putty logging and saw:

Event Log: Local port 1433 forwarding to RemoteServer:1433 failed: Network error: Permission denied
Event Log: Local port 1434 forwarding to RemoteServer:1433 failed: Network error: Permission denied

On my router (D-Link) port 1433 is closed. And I do not want to open it.

So I change putty setting: L1433 RemoteServerIP: 22
New Log:
Event Log: Local port 1433 forwarding to RemoteServer:22 failed: Network error: Permission denied

Comment: Do you have ssh access (correct credentials) to the remote host? Try a simple ssh connection to the host. You will need to provide the same credentials during tunnel setup.

Comment: Thanks, this is obvious now, but just didnt occur to me when i hit this issue, Putty doesnt balk at or report tunnel port conflicts in a useful way.